# check for falsy values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove elements with falsy values from an array, but my code is not behaving that way. I want to know why my code does not work. Here is the code

```js
let g= [7, null, "ate", "", false, true, 9];

g.forEach((cur,ind,arr) => {
    if (!cur) {
        arr.splice(ind,1);
    }
});

console.log(g);
```

Here is the output

`[7, "ate", false, true, 9]`

Comment: Modifying an array while you're iterating over it is… pretty weird. Simply `g = g.filter(i => i)` would do.

Comment: you change the array, but `forEach` knows still the old values/indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forEach function doesn't detect if you delete elements, so when you modify the array, it will skip elements. The best way to do what you want is:

```
g.filter(e => e);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
g.filter(Boolean);
```

Should be enough to solve your problem.

If you call the constructor of `Boolean` with any value, it will cast them as boolean, so all truthy values will be accepted by the filter.

Using `.filter` will create a new array from your original array `g` but only keep the truthy values.

It is actually the more concise way I found so far, but it is totally equivalent to the following method.

```
g.filter(el => el);
```

Because the expression will implicitly cast the element to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

```
const result = g.filter(val => val);
//or if you want to be superfluous like me
const result = g.filter(val => !!val);
// output [7, "ate", true, 9]
```

Comment: `!!val` → `val`.

Comment: Yeah but I vaguely remeber reading somewhere that using !! will change each value to a boolean if its not?

Comment: Yeah, it does change it to a boolean, but that's superfluous. Javascript does that anyway in a boolean context (i.e. when it needs a *truthy* or *falsey* value).

Comment: It's superfluous in the context of the `filter()` function since it returns based on truthiness. In other methods this may not be the case and that is when the double bang (`!!`) is helpful.

Comment: ah yes, of course